# Set Icon for a button: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mapbox

I'm trying to set an icon for a button in react, but it's getting me this error.
The setIcon of the Button functionality and the button is like this from the source code:

```
class Button {
  node: HTMLButtonElement
  icon: SVGElement

  constructor() {
    this.node = document.createElement('button');
    this.node.type = 'button';
    this.icon = null;
  }

  setIcon(icon: SVGElement) {
    this.icon = icon;
    this.node.appendChild(icon);
  }
```

The button is from a librabry that written in TypeScript as mapbox control button.

The icon I am using is from MUI,

```
import AdjustIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Adjust'
```

What I did is `this.back.setIcon(AdjustIcon);` And `this.back.setIcon(<AdjustIcon/>);` Both are not working and give the same error message：

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: have you tried cutting out the .node? and just went to this.appendChild?

Comment: This is from the library source code, and the .node is actually the html button

Comment: ok yeah, makes sense.  Wasn't 100% on what the back element was.  Question update makes it a lot clearer what the scope of the back element is :)

Comment: do you need to define the icon as a node type element?

Comment: Can you define type in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed, `<AdjustIcon/>` is a react element but not a DOM node.

However `.appendchild()` is expecting a DOM node as parameter, and that caused the error.

The solution of this is convert `<AdjustIcon/>` to a DOM node, and I was using `ReactDOM.render()` to do that.

```
    const container = document.createElement('icon');
    ReactDOM.render(<AdjustIcon />, container);
    this.back.setIcon(container);
```

Using `document.createElement()` to create a container, and call `ReactDOM.render()` to render the icon into that container. Then just simply use that container as the icon node.